# Populating live <select> element after hitting javascript:history.go(-1) button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I've been struggling with a problem for a while.

I have one  element with the following default state:

```
<select name="model"></select>
```

There's a live event hooked which populates the above element with options:

```
<select name="model">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
    <option value="Piazza">Piazza</option>
    <option value="Pickup">Pickup</option>
</select>
```

Afterwards there's a SerializeObject function which converts the form key-val pairs to json and sends it to the PHP controller.

Afterwards the results are displayed on the page with ajax.
When the user clicks on a result, he is sent to the detailed page which has a "BACK" button at the top. Here's the back button:

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

When the user clicks it, he gets to the previous results page. Every select element but the "model" one is properly populated with the expected data. I am assuming the reason lies in the fact that its contents were generated with an ajax request and a `.html()` overwrite.

I did a cross browser check: doesn't work on Chrome 36, doesn't work on IE 9 and works perfectly on Firefox 30.

Forgot to mention: I have `header("Cache-control: private");`  activated.

I hope somebody comes with a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: use cookies to store the last values. check if the cookies are set, and populate the fields as desired. then instead of inline javascript back button, use window location reload when the button is clicked, or navigate manually to the desired url. now when they use the button, the fields should be populated correctly. its a more complicated solution, but it is the right solution, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your current implementation will vary across browsers/versions. I'd use something like [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to make this easier.

When you populate your select element, save the data you used into the current history state object. Then when the browser state changes, reload your options from the data currently in the 'history state' at the new index.